# how to add more than one prefix - JDA

Tags: java, bots, discord-jda

I would like to know how could I add more than one prefix to my discord bot?

This is my current prefix listener code, the prefix is being pulled from a .env

```
final long guildId = event.getGuild().getIdLong();
String prefix = Config.get("PREFIX");
String raw = event.getMessage().getContentRaw();

if (raw.startsWith(prefix)) {
    manager.handle(event, prefix);
}
```

Currently my bot's prefix is based on mention <@!ID>, but this type of mention doesn't work on mobile discord (mobile discord uses only <@ID> for mention, without the "!"), so I would like to add both variants to be used on my bot.

I was told I could use regex for that but I have no clue how it works and how to apply it to my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define a second prefix and check, if the message starts with one of them.

```java
final long guildId = event.getGuild().getIdLong();
String prefix1 = Config.get("PREFIX1");
String prefix2 = Config.get("PREFIX2");
String raw = event.getMessage().getContentRaw();

if (raw.startsWith(prefix1) || raw.startsWith(prefix2) {
    //...
}
```